# Exception in thread "main" - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: appium, appium-ios

This issue occurred after the first steps.
OS: Mac

I have declared `DesiredCapabilities` and trying to run the IPhone simulator using Xcode.

```
public class DC_Demo{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities des = new DesiredCapabilities();
        des.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone X");
        des.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "IOS");
        des.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.IOS_XCUI_TEST);
        des.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "//Macintosh HD⁩//Users⁩//isururodrigo⁩//Development//VS-Staging.app⁩");
        IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),des);

    }
}
```

Error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   at DC_Demo_VisitSinga.main(DC_Demo_VisitSinga.java:21)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Maven project, then in your `pom.xml` file, add latest version of guava library.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>27.0.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Or if you're using Java project, then download latest version of the same library and add it in your build path.

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I had to start a Maven project, problem solved. Thanks